# Phoronix Test Suite "Allowed Memory Size Exhausted" under 22.04

Tags: php, benchmarks

I installed Phoronix Test Suite 10.8.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 using the deb package from their website.  Up until a couple of weeks ago, it worked without issues.  Now when I run a benchmark, I get an error like this:

```
Started Run 1 @ 11:29:41PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 534773792 bytes) in /usr/share/phoronix-test-suite/pts-core/objects/client/pts_test_execution.php on line 298
```

PTS depends on PHP, and I noticed in `/var/log/apt/history.log`, there were several updates to PHP (to 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9).  I checked my `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` file and the `memory_limit` is set to `-1`, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.  Does anyone know what change might have caused the problem that I'm seeing, or how I might fix this?

Edit:
This is the block where PTS is failing (Edit edit: the right line).  It's failing on the `$test_result_std_output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);` line.

```
  if(is_resource($test_process))
  {       
    //echo proc_get_status($test_process)['pid'];
    pts_module_manager::module_process('__test_running', $test_process);
    $test_result_std_output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $return_value = proc_close($test_process);
  }
```

Comment: Does your server have only 1GB of RAM? Is anything else running on the server at the same time? 

Comment: No, the machine has 64 GB of RAM and PTS is the only thing running.

Comment: which benchmark, or is it any benchmark? I'll try the same benchmark, but I only have a server and can not run some benchmarks. Please post line 298 of `pts_test_execution.php` as mine seems to be different (I run from a git clone of Phoronix).

Comment: I was using the pts/tww3 benchmark.  Not in front of the machine right now but I'll update the question with that line when I get back.

Comment: tww3 is a graphics type test. I can not run it on my server. There have only been about 20 commits since v10.8.4, and none seem related to your issue.

Comment: I tried running with the cloned version from github too; no change.

Comment: ...and when I try with another test, it works.  Seems like just that test is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had MangoHud turned on in debug mode, which was posting a lot more output to stdout than the Phoronix suite could handle.  Once I turned it off, it started working.